# Hidden id for selected text in Android AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, sqlite, autocomplete

I have a very basic form in my Android App. One of the fields has to be selected from the rows in my SQLite db.
As this field offers a LOT of options, a spinner would be unconfortable for the user, so I opted for an autocomplete field, as the user usually knows the name of the item he's looking for.
So, now I have an AutoCompleteTextView against a SQLite DB table. The autocomplete functionality is working just fine:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, new String[]{"nombre"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);       

AutoCompleteTextView concepto = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editConcepto);
    concepto.setAdapter(adapter);

final PorkyOpenHelper poh = new PorkyOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());

adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() 
{           
    @Override
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence str) 
    {
        if (str != null)
        {
            return poh.findConceptosByNombre(str.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
});

adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() 
{
    @Override
    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) 
    {
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(PorkyOpenHelper.CONCEPTOS_TABLE_NOMBRE);
        return cursor.getString(index);
        }
});
```

But now I have a problem: the users selects and sees the field 'nombre' from my db table, but I need to know and store the '_id' field. I could solve it with try-n-fix, but I'd like to know if there's some more elegant or 'correct' solution already proben for the Android SDK (yes, the quotes in correct are a joke).

Thanks in advance everyone!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use OnItemClickListener, the last param of the callback is the item id

Comment: Isn't that param the index of the item in the list displayed? I need the _id from the db, not the position in the list of the autocomplete field.

Comment: onItemClick (AdapterView<?>
parent, View view, int
position, long id), the last one is id not position

Comment: also use setStringConversionColumn instead of setCursorToStringConverter

Comment: This will give you Auto Complete Text View id not a database id which associated with that column

Comment: @Pravin excuse me? what do you mean?

Comment: i am asking for database id which is belong to that record

Comment: @Pravin the last parameter of `onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` is a **database id**, it is not Auto Complete Text View id, see how this id is created in CursorAdapter: http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#221